# How to fix encoding issues ? (NSString / XMLParsing)

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, nsxmlparser

I parsed an XML file containing UTF8/latin characters (é, â, è, î, etc...).

At first I tried to fix this with a function replacing the wrong chars. But I'm having a problem with **à**, replaced by **"**.
And as I don't want to replace all the **"** of my file, I have to find another way to fix it.

Any idea to fix this ?

Thanks a lot for your advices

Comment: It results `"` when you're `NSLogging` or when you're trying to set it in a NSString? I ask because sometimes, when I'm `NSLogging` special characters, it result something like: "√2", and when I set it to a NSString, it becomes normal.

Comment: No it's while setting it in the NSString. But after reflexion is think it's not because of my program but rather of the XML file.

Comment: Is your XML `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`?

Comment: No it's `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>`, so I guess here is the error. I'm going to tell it to the webmaster (it's not me that manages the XML file I'm working on).

Comment: Well, so here is the error. Tell to the webmaster change it, and your code will work with special characters. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finally answer this question, it worked [using TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html). But only with UTF-8 encoding, not ISO-8859-1.