# I'm still having UTF-8 encoding issues with NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, nsxmlparser, nsxml

So I fixed my XML file and the PCDATA was indeed caused by the wrong encoding (**ISO8859-1** wasn't right, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789547)), but I still have incorrect chars using both ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 encodings.

The problem is when I parse my file and get the chars :

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"%@", foundCharacters);
    [self.currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}
```

If I have for example the "é" char, it will be transformed into "È".

What should I do ? Help !
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please try to formulate standalone questions. If we need to look at your previous question to get enough context for this question you'll get less help as a result.

Comment: Please use a hex editor (or `hexdump -C` from the command line) to find out the exact sequence of bytes being used to represent the é and then add it to your question.  Note that, it might be decomposed as an e followed by the accent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working [by using TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html).